# PHPUnit - Assert two XMLs are not equal

Tags: php, xml, phpunit

I have just started introduction some PHPUnit tests to my application and want to compare two XML files that get generated. The positive test is not an issue, since there is a dedicated method to do so:

```
$this->assertEqualXMLStructure(
  $expectedResultXml->firstChild,
  $generatedResultXml->firstChild
);
```

Now, I have been looking to write a negative test where I purposely create an invalid XML so they no longer match. I have been googling for some time now, but I can't seem to find a good solution (something like a method called `assertNotEqualXMLStructure();`). I am really new to PHP so this might be a noob question; sorry if that is the case here.

How can I test that two XML files are not equal based on their structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no method like `assertNotEqualXMLStructure()` because it is not needed. Since your two XML documents have a different structure, their text representation cannot be the same.

You can use `DOMNode::C14N()` to produce the canonical representation of the two nodes as text and assert the text representations are not equal (using [`$this->assertNotEquals()`](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.assertions.html#appendixes.assertions.assertEquals)):

```
$this->assertNotEquals(
    $expectedResultXml->firstChild->C14N(),
    $generatedResultXml->firstChild->C14N()
);
```

Comment: Thx for the input.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered comparing their values in PHP? You can convert XML to PHP using this:

`$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_string);
 $json = json_encode($xml);
 $array = json_decode($json,TRUE);`

Then you can compare the structure that is returned in the array (the attributes are split up as well in the result)